# DirectX 11 EnumOutputs Fail with NVIDIA Card, Win 8

Tags: directx-11

My error should be commented out in the following code. I have tried mixing things around in many Wais, but whatever I do the "EnumOutputs" function won't work when I try force it to use use my GeForce GTX 765M card. And as far as I know I need that pdxgiOutput to later make of my GetDisplayModeList1();

Hope this will be information enough to see what the problem is.

```
std::vector <IDXGIAdapter1*> availableAdapters;

while (m_pIDXGIFactory->EnumAdapters1(m_adapterIndex, &pdxgiAdapter) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
    {
    availableAdapters.push_back(pdxgiAdapter);
    ++m_adapterIndex;
    }
pdxgiAdapter = availableAdapters[1];  // NVIDIA GeForce GTX 765M
//pdxgiAdapter = availableAdapters[0]; // Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600

pdxgiAdapter->EnumOutputs(0, &pdxgiOutput); // !!**Failure when use NVIDIA Gefore 765M!**
```

> Debug Assertion failed: C:\ProgramFiles\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\VC\include\vector Line: 1201
>
> Expression: vector subscript out of range

Answer (score 0):

The assert you're getting sounds like it's coming from your use of the subscript operator on the "availableAdapters" vector, not from EnumOutputs.

Have you tried printing out the .size() of the vector prior to accessing the 2nd element to check there's actually two things in it? Is it not possible that your laptop (?) has two GPUs but only one is enumerable at any given time and are switched on/off in the BIOS (or by some other means)?

Answer (score 0):

Im a beginner to this, but could try set it up another way:

```
std::vector <IDXGIAdapter1*> availableAdapters;
while (m_pIDXGIFactory->EnumAdapters1(m_adapterIndex, &pdxgiAdapter) != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND)
    {
    availableAdapters.push_back(pdxgiAdapter);
    ++m_adapterIndex;
    }

pdxgiAdapter = availableAdapters[1];  // NVIDIA GeForce GTX 765M
//pdxgiAdapter = availableAdapters[0]; // Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600

pdxgiAdapter->GetDesc1(&AdapterDesc);
if (AdapterDesc.DedicatedVideoMemory)
    {
    m_videoCardMemory = AdapterDesc.DedicatedVideoMemory;
    }
else
    {
    m_videoCardMemory = AdapterDesc.SharedSystemMemory;
    }
pdxgiAdapter->EnumOutputs(m_outputIndex, &pdxgiOutput));
```

And when I try With bouth availableAdapters[1] or [0] the GetDesc find bouth the Intel and GeForce - card. But fails in the EnumOutpts With the Geforce, Leaves pdxgiOutput = 0x00000000000000